# what are possible properties for transaction manager? What do they mean?

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, applicationcontext

Following is my part of my applicationContext.xml

I am getting lazyinitialization exceptions for simple finder methods. How can I change following xml to avoid lazy loading exceptions?

I also want to know what are possible prop keys. In my XML I see loadSingle, but I do not know that what means. Where can I find list of possible properties?

```
<bean id="baseTransactionProxy" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean" abstract="true">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
   <property name="transactionAttributes">
     <props>
       <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,readOnly</prop>
       <prop key="loadSingle">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
     </props>
   </property>
  </bean>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Property keys are method names. From documentation:

> Set properties with method names as keys and transaction attribute
>   descriptors (parsed via TransactionAttributeEditor) as values: e.g.
>   key = "myMethod", value = "PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly".

So your configuration basically means `loadSingle` method will execute transactionally and all other methods will support transaction and will be read only. [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionProxyFactoryBean.html#setTransactionAttributes%28java.util.Properties%29) is the official documentation.